# Google Analytics only tracking obout 10% of my online orders

Tags: google, google-analytics

I am using Actinic Ecommerce software and have enabled Google Analytics tracking. The tracking itself works fine.

But when it comes to the Ecommerce order tracking i am having problems, it registered about 3 out of 15 orders that came in.

I have compared the orders and no obvious difference jump out at me.

Any ideas?

http://www.pretty-small-shoes.com/acatalog/

Comment: Do the orders that aren't coming through have apostrophes in their product names?

Comment: One of the orders missed did have a - in it but then the other didn't

Answer (score 1):

Three possibilities:

1) The software doesn't have the correct analytics code everywhere that's it's required.
2) You haven't configured the analytics correctly through the software.
3) You have a heavy number of users using no track plugins or addons like Firefox's request policy that blocks third party domains unless the users explicitly enables them. I run request policy on FF myself, it's use and similar tools is common amongst certain technical communities and what your product is for would give a hint as to whether this is the likely issue.

Aside, my wife is a shoe size 2 and you've just made her day.

Comment: #1 and #2 are more likely, considering the proportions. (Also, as a men's size 14, I cannot imagine how someone can stand stably on a women's 2.)

Comment: #1 and #2 are excellent points, 
#1 is there a way of checking where all the code is required?
#2 is there a way of comparing the code?